# Group Highchart time data into weeks and months

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am using highcharts in my application to display total production in a certain time period. The chart is depicted in the following snapshot:
[image: Highchart for range]

First issue I have is that when I select a date range greater than the range I have in the image, the bar chart doesn't show at all. (though data is there). It looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way that I can group these fields into may be weeks (if data is greater than 50 days) and months (if data is greater than 100 days) using highcharts? Or do I have to recompile the data into weekly and monthly estimates from the server side and feed that data separately into the chart?

Comment: do you have a js-fiddle example so that we can look at at your code and guide you well

Comment: In Highstock you can use [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping) feature. In Highcharts you need to do this on your own.

Comment: @PawełFus so can I use HighStock for the chart above?

Comment: If you have license for Highstock, then yes, you can use Highcharts for your charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had to do this manually with my data because I did not use highstocks.